# no return, in function returning non-void {in eclipse CDT}

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt

```
Save=0;
bool checking() const; ///declaration

inline bool isZombie() const  //definition
{ if(Save==0)   {return cc_t < 0}
  if(Save==1)  {return cc_i < 0;}
}
```

it's a very naive question. I understand the meaning of the error in the code. Can anyone tell me, why it is not accepting return statements in conditions.
if I write the above code as

```
bool checking() const  //definition
{ if(Save==0)   {return cc_t < 0}
  else {return cc_i < 0;}
}
```

then, there are no warnings..?

Comment: what is the type of 'Save' ?

Comment: Simply because this way `return` statement may never be reached

Comment: Your code is missing a `;`, it is otherwise legal if a bad idea.  The warning is because if save is 3, your code executes undefined behaviour.

Comment: What happens in your `isZombie` function when `Save` is 2 or more?

Answer (score 3):

What's the type of `Save` actually? You're missing a `return` statement in the rest of possible branches. What is so unclear about that warning?

```
inline bool isZombie() const  //definition
{ if(Save==0)   {return cc_t < 0;}
                             // ^ Supposed this is a typo
  if(Save==1)  {return cc_i < 0;}
  return false; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

Comment: Even if Save is a bool I would not be shocked if eclipse misses the logic.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ 's example allows your if to be processed twice (which is generally bad design) however; functionally it's return the first, the second or default to false. The default to false is the key here.

Comment: @JohanLundberg Do you actually believe it's a matter of Eclipse-CDT?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I'm just speculating: In case `Save` was a `bool` I would not expect clang or gcc to warn about the shown code.

Comment: @JohanLundberg Exactly, it would be a matter of the tool chain used, not Eclipse CTD, unless intellisense is mentioned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. Well *intellisence* is MS wording right? Since the question is about Eclipse CTD I thought this was really an IDE warning, (red underline etc). And the question lacks pasted compiler warning or mentioning of gcc/clang.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's best to have a sure path of return.

For example, one *could* write it as (and keeping your code mostly untouched):

```
inline bool isZombie() const { 
   if(Save==0)
      return cc_t < 0;
  else
       return cc_i < 0;
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```
inline bool isZombie() const { 
  bool rVal = (cc_i < 0); 
  if(Save==0)
     return cc_t < 0;
  return rVal;
}
```

Comment: Or `return ((Save == 0) ? cc_t : cc_i) < 0;`

Comment: Indeed, but I wanted to keep and easily traceable logic in his present format. For some people readability generates better understanding. Not that it takes your suggestion from being any more correct, depending on his C++ exposure that may be harder to mentally parse.